# android application crashes with no errors

Tags: android, dictionary

i am trying out an android map application, when i run it there are no errors or problems in the code, i use my samsung galaxy s3 to test it but it keeps on displaying >"Unfortunately, maps has stopped".

**Here's my java file**

```
package com.maps;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends MapActivity {

MapView map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

**Here is my xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyAfv657yXaBMlBLAe2pw0VyJiPLiczDG7E"
    android:id="@+id/mvMain"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.maps.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: I agree with Raghav Sood, there should be something in the LogCat. See what's the error there and paste it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383353/android-unfortunately-google-maps-stopped?rq=1

Comment: please post your logcat\

Answer (score 0):

A crash when using maps is often due to a bad API key. Double check that the key you are using is valid

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Maps v2 for Android.
Here you have a [good tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw).
Anyway, your problem seems to be with the API key.

Answer (score 0):

If GOOGLE API is not valid it will not show map that's it .
Why don't you attach your manifest.xml file so that we can rectify your error. 
Otherwise check manifest file whether it contains reference of GOOGLEapi or not.